# Assigning to 'id<UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>' from incompatible type 'ViewController *const__strong'

Tags: ios, xcode, delegates, uiimagepickercontroller, incompatibletypeerror

I have an ImagePickerController in my application.
It works well, but beside `ipc.delegate = self;` there appears an error message:

> Assigning to
>   'id'
>   from incompatible type 'ViewController *const__strong'

The app workes well, so I ignored the error message, but I think I need to know why. Why is the error message appearing?

```
ipc = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
            ipc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
            ipc.delegate = self;
            ipc.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
            [ipc setAllowsEditing:NO];
            [self presentViewController:ipc animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you take a look at the definition of the `UIImagePickerController` delegate property, you'll see it defined as:

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) id<UINavigationControllerDelegate, 
                                UIImagePickerControllerDelegate> delegate
```

Whatever object you set as the delegate (in this case you are using `self`) must conform to both the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` protocol and the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` protocol. If the object does not conform to both of these protocols, you'll get a compile-time warning.

Here's how you declare that your class conforms to the protocols:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate, 
                                                UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
```

Read up on [working with protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html), [UINavigationControllerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html), and [UIImagePickerControllerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html).

Comment: I already added them in the 'ViewController.h' file. That's why I have no idea why the error is appearing.

Comment: @홍승욱 Make sure you declare that your class conforms to the protocol. `@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>`

Answer (score 5):

I just ran into this for the first time.  If your class extends another class which conforms to other protocols, and your class also conforms to these two protocols `<UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>` then in order to remove the warning, you must cast it, like this:

```
ipc.delegate = (id<<UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>) self;
```

Personally, I think this is a bug in the compiler, in that you do adhere to both protocols, you just also happen to adhere to others.  Therefore, you shouldn't have to see the warning.